# Android theme in library project

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, manifest

I have a library project providing a few activities. Some are immersive, and I need the action bar to be created. On the other hand, the clients using the library must be able to customize its theme (mainly the colors).

One of my clients is using the Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme, which removes the action bar from my activities.

Is there a way to ensure that the action bar will be shown (so, my activities' themes have to inherit from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar), while leaving the colors customizable?

Programmatically creating the action bar would be fine, but I'm not sure that this is possible, right?

EDIT: It works if my client declare the library's activities in their manifest, and set a DarkActionBar theme on each. But I'd really prefer to avoid that solution, as currently they don't have to declare our activities thanks to the manifest merger.

Comment: Did you solve this?